Generic types with dynamic mandatory key of specific type
Edit: Solution below https://stackoverflow.com/a/78438593/19831401
I have a Generic typescript type that accepts the key name for text and value as a generic parameter: type Options<T, TKey, VKey> where TKey is the key for the text, VKey the key for the value.
/**
 * Here are my types
 */
type Option<
  T,
  TKey extends PropertyKey,
  VKey extends PropertyKey
> = { [key: PropertyKey]: unknown } & { [K in TKey]: string } & { [K in VKey]: T };

type Options<
  T = unknown,
  TKey extends PropertyKey = "text",
  VKey extends PropertyKey = "value"
> = Array<Option<T, TKey, VKey>>;


/**
 * Question: How can I make a Typescript interface that infer properly TKey and VKey from Options<T, TKey, VKey> properly based on the value passed to
 * textProperty and valueProperty?
 */

// The interface
interface MySelectProps<T> {
  value: T;
  textProperty: PropertyKey; // Defaults to 'text'
  valueProperty: PropertyKey; // Defaults to 'value'
  options: Options<T, MySelectProps<T>['textProperty'], MySelectProps<T>['valueProperty']>;
}

// Exemples
const myProps: MySelectProps<string> = {
  value: "1",
  textProperty: "label",
  valueProperty: "value",
  options: [/* ... */] // Should expect Options<string, "label", "value">
}

const myProps2: MySelectProps<string> = {
  value: "1",
  textProperty: "myTextProperty",
  valueProperty: "myValueProperty",
  options: [/* ... */] // Should expect Options<string, "myTextProperty", "myValueProperty">
}

I'm unable to write an interface type that will infer properly Options<T, TKey, VKey> properly depending on the values passed to textProperty and valueProperty.
Exemple
const myProps2: MySelectProps<string> = {
  value: "1",
  textProperty: "myTextProperty",
  valueProperty: "myValueProperty",
  options: [/* ... */] // Should expect Options<string, "myTextProperty", "myValueProperty">
}

Because i'm passing
textProperty: "myTextProperty",
valueProperty: "myValueProperty",

expected options type is supposed to be of type Options<T, "myTextProperty", "myValueProperty">
Here is a typescript playground for easy testing Playground

It appeared that it wasn't possible to do what I want in Typescript.
However, by trying to do the opposite: validating the key presence on the type options dynamically I was able to get the exact result I wanted to.
Opposite way
Defining TKey and VKey as generic type on MySelectProps was problematic for me because I couldn't define those value based on textProperty and valueProperty.
As a workaround, setting generic type to TKey and VKey when I use the interface allows me to validate that textProperty and valueProperty is defined on options. It required to force cast textProperty to TKey and valueProperty to VKey.
export interface SvSelectProps<T, TKey extends string, VKey extends string> {
  value: T;
  textProperty?: TKey,
  valueProperty?: VKey,
  options: Options<T, TKey, VKey>;
}

/**
 * Svelte component demo
 */
<script lang="ts" generics="T, TKey extends string, VKey extends string">
  let {
    options,
    value,
    textProperty = "text" as TKey, // Forcing the cast sets the value of TKey to textProperty
    valueProperty = "value" as VKey,  // Forcing the cast sets the value of VKey to valueProperty
  }: SvSelectProps<T, TKey, VKey> = $props();
</script>

Usage
// SomePage.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import MySelect, { type MySelectProps } from "$lib";

  let options: Options<string, "text", "value"> = [
    { value: "1", text: "One" },
    { value: "2", text: "Two" },
    { value: "3", text: "Three" },
  ];
</script>

<SvSelect
  value="1"
  textProperty="texttypo" // TS: Type '"texttypo"' is not assignable to type '"text"'.ts(2322)
  valueProperty="value" 
  options={options} />

Final solution
It seems that passing generic type to TKey and VKey and force casting them made possible to do exactly what I wanted to do. It requires to not type options because when it's typed, typescript warns about the textProperty/valueProperty being not present in options.
// SomePage.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import MySelect, { type MySelectProps } from "$lib";

  // See: untyped
  let options = [
    { value: "1", text: "One" },
    { value: "2", text: "Two" },
    { value: "3", text: "Three" },
  ];
</script>

<SvSelect
  value="1"
  textProperty="texttypo" 
  valueProperty="value" 
  options={options} // Type '{ value: string; text: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Options<string, "texttypo", "value">'.
 />


The problem here is that types for textProperty and valueProperty in MySelectProps interface aren't aligned with options you're passing: Options<string, "label", "value">.
Both textProperty and valueProperty are of type PropertyKey, which is string | number | symbol, while you pass exact values for these fields: "label" and "value". While they're strings, the compiler regards the exact values and strings as different types (see Literal types). You may fix it by declaring Options<string, PropertyKey, PropertyKey> on the line 20.
Here's a revised code without the hack suggested above:
type Option<
  T,
  TKey extends PropertyKey,
  VKey extends PropertyKey
> = { [key: string]: unknown } & { [K in TKey]: string } & { [K in VKey]: T };

type Options<
  T = unknown,
  TKey extends PropertyKey = "text",
  VKey extends PropertyKey = "value"
> = Option<T, TKey, VKey>[];

type MySelectProps<T, TKey extends PropertyKey = "text", VKey extends PropertyKey = "value"> = {
  value: T;
  textProperty: TKey; // Defaults to 'text'
  valueProperty: VKey; // Defaults to 'value'
  options: Options<T, TKey, VKey>;
}

let options: Options<string, "label", "value"> = [
  { value: "1", label: "One" },
  { value: "2", label: "Two" },
  { value: "3", label: "Three" },
  { value: "4", label: "Four" },
  { value: "5", label: "Five" },
  { value: "6", label: "Six" }
];

const myProps: MySelectProps<string, "label", "value"> = {
  value: "1",
  textProperty: "label",
  valueProperty: "value",
  options,
}

It's a bit more inconvenient because you need to specify "label" and "value" multiple times, but you can do like this:
type TKey = "label";
type VKey = "value";

let options: Options<string, TKey, VKey> = [
  { value: "1", label: "One" },
  { value: "2", label: "Two" },
  { value: "3", label: "Three" },
  { value: "4", label: "Four" },
  { value: "5", label: "Five" },
  { value: "6", label: "Six" }
];

const myProps: MySelectProps<string, TKey, VKey> = {
  value: "1",
  textProperty: "label",
  valueProperty: "value",
  options,
}

You may also want to replace PropertyKey with string since it'll be a more appropriate type you expect if an Option isn't an object that can have symbol or number keys.

Is there a way to not specify TKey, VKey as a generic type to MySelectProps? I'm asking because the way you suggested the value of TKey and VKey are not decided by textProperty and valueProperty but by the generic types passed to MySelectProps which is the opposite of what I am trying to do. Basically I would like this: Options<T, valueOf textProperty, valueOf valueProperty>>

No,  since you're looking at a runtime types validation that Typescript doesn't support: it can't infer runtime types from textProperty and valueProperty values.

I have clarified my question because it ain't a runtime type so I believe I wasn't clear enough

Inference of the type you want can be done with a function that returns a value.  This code infers the values of PKey and VKey so any changes in the select object properties also dictates changes to the options property.
type Option<T, PKey extends string, VKey extends string> = Record<PKey, string> &
  Record<VKey, T>;

// The interface
interface SelectProps<T, PKey extends string, VKey extends string> {
  value: T;
  textProperty: PKey; // Defaults to 'text'
  valueProperty: VKey; // Defaults to 'value'
  options: Option<T, PKey, VKey>[];
}

declare function propsBuilder<T, PKey extends string, VKey extends string>(
  arg: SelectProps<T, PKey, VKey>,
): SelectProps<T, PKey, VKey>;

const test = propsBuilder({
  value: 1,
  textProperty: "label",
  valueProperty: "value",
  options: [{label:"foo", value:2}, {label:"bar", value:55}],
});

const test1 = propsBuilder({
    value:"hello", 
    textProperty:"foo_property", 
    valueProperty:"bar_property", 
    options:[{
        foo_property:"wow", bar_property:"now"
    }]
})

Here is a TS playground showing how this works. https://tsplay.dev/mxpa1m

This is very nice as well! I wonder if this is what is happening behind the scene in the Svelte exemple I left. However I'm a bit surprised: doesn't propsBuilder need an actual implementation of the function? Why does it work?

Props Builder would need an implementation, though I imagine it would just return the args you passed in.  I believe its called an identity function.  Declaring a variable/function defines it's parameters and return type without needing implementation.    I'm not familiar with JSX in Svelt, but in react JSX is simply an alias for a function call, so this same type of generic would work for a component and it's props.
